# Hold BattleShip hits and misses in BattleShip Game Program C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to teach myself C++ so I am doing a Battleship program. I have a Ship, Board and BattleShip Driver class.

This version is fairly standard. The player enters the coordinates of a cell to try to hit a ship. The program stating if a ship is hit. If all cells occupied by a ship are hit, the program prints a message stating that that ship is sunk. After each attempt, the program prints the current state by showing the board with all successful attempts marked by "*" or "x"respectively.

I have a board for the Battleships

```
   a b c d e f g h i j
  +-------------------+
 0|                   |
 1|                   |
 2|                   |
 3|                   |
 4|                   |
 5|                   |
 6|                   |
 7|                   |
 8|                   |
 9|                   |
  +-------------------+
```

So my Board Constructor initializes my scores array with spaces.

```
char score[10][10]
```

is array of char storing the current state of each cell of the board, with char 'x' and '*' representing unsuccessful and successful attempts respectively, and ' ' (space) in cells that were not hit.

Here is my Board Class:

```
#include "Board.h"
#include "Ship.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdexcept>


//member function definitions

Board::Board(void)

{
    char score[10][10] = {' '};
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            score[i][j] = ' ';
        }
}

}

void Board::addShip(char type, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) 
{
    if(shipList.size()<10)
        {
            shipList.push_back(Ship::makeShip(type,x1,y1,x2,y2));
        }
}

void Board::print(void){

 cout<< "   a b c d e f g h i j"<< endl;
    cout <<"  +-------------------+"<< endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // print the first character as part of the opener.
        cout<< " " << i << "|" << score[i][0];
        for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
           // only add spaces for subsequent characters.
           cout << " " << score[i][j];
        }
        cout << "          |" << endl;
    }
    cout <<"  +-------------------+"<< endl;
}

void Board::hit(char c, int i){

    if (c<'a' || c>'j' || i > 9 || i<0){
        throw invalid_argument("invalid input");
    }

    Ship* ship = shipAt(i, c-'a');


    if (ship) {
        score[i][c-'a']= '*';
    }
    else{
        score[i][c-'a']= 'x';

    }

}

Ship* Board::shipAt(int x, int y)
{
  for(Ship* ship : shipList){
    if(ship->Ship::includes(x, y)){
        return ship;
    }
    else{
        return NULL;
    }
    }

}

int Board::level(void)
{
    int lev = 0;
    std::vector<Ship *>::iterator iter = shipList.begin();
    std::vector<Ship *>::iterator end = shipList.end();
    for ( ; iter != end; ++iter )
    {
       lev += (*iter)->level();
    }

    return lev;

}
```

Unfortunately my output is wrong no matter how much I change my functions I get output like the following: (As you can see the right vertical line is pushed out to the right every hit.

```
   a b c d e f g h i j
  +-------------------+
 0|*                   |
 1|                   |
 2|                   |
 3|   x                |
 4|                   |
 5|                   |
 6|                   |
 7|                   |
 8|                   |
 9|                   |
  +-------------------+
```

I tried to reimplement my `void Board::print(void)` ,  `void Board::hit(char c, int i)`, and re-do my Board constructor, but nothing seems to be working the error keeps on persisting. My board keeps on getting pushed out to the right. I'm not sure how could this be fixed.

Ideally I would output like to produce output like following:

```
  a b c d e f g h i j
  +-------------------+
 0|                   |
 1|                   |
 2|                   |
 3|                   |
 4|                   |
 5|                   |
 6|                   |
 7|                   |
 8|          x        |
 9|                   |
  +-------------------+
   a b c d e f g h i j
  +-------------------+
 0|                   |
 1|                   |
 2|                   |
 3|                   |
 4|                   |
 5|                   |
 6|                   |
 7|                   |
 8|          x   *    |
 9|                   |
  +-------------------+
```

Comment: use ios::fixed, it will keep width fixed and thus won't change after character is updated

Comment: Also the `cout << "          |" << endl;` line misalign the ending `|`. Every line should simply end with `cout << "|" << endl;`

Comment: every line? That doesn't align with the format I posted above though

Comment: Yes, the problem is the `cout << "          |" << endl;` as @NirMH mentioned. After your last cell state in the current line, you append a lot of spaces and *then* the vertical bar. But the desired output you described should just print the vertical bar after the last cell state and then break the line.

Comment: When I change it to that I get my vertical lines "|" in the middle of the board

Comment: Yes, that's because of what @n-o-d wrote in his answer (which you should maybe accept by the way since it describes the problem well, which actually consists of two errors). I will try to explain the exact behaviour again:

Comment: In the constructor `Board::Board()` you declare a `char` array `score` and fill it with spaces. This is a local variable here and cannot be seen inside the `print` method. Since you are using `score` there, it has to be a global variable that is missing above, or you'd be getting a compile error.

Comment: Now I suppose this global `score` is not initialized with spaces (you're initializing the local one instead), and thus every time you `print`, you are printing one space with `cout << " " << score[i][j]` instead of two, because `score[i][j]` is no space. After that, you append `"          |"`, so you have exactly 19 spaces in your current line. But once you fill one of the `score[i][j]` with an actual content, your line is becoming longer by 1, causing the ragged right side.

Comment: Assuming you have defined a global `score` somewhere, the fix might even be as simple as deleting the word `char` in the first line of the constructor, thus filling the correct global variable instead of the local one.

Answer (score 2):

I guess score is a member variable. But in the constructor you hide it by declaring a local variable using the same name:

`Board::Board(void)
{
    char score[10][10] = {' '};`

This way the member is not initialized.

in Board::print(void) the line
   `cout << "          |" << endl;`
should be
   `cout << "|" << endl;`

I tested the print() method and it looked ok. Can't see any reason why the length of the output could increase.

Comment: oops, sorry, instead of cout I used `ostringstream ccout; ccout << whatever` and later `OutputDebugStringA(ccout.str().c_str());` to get the output.

Comment: does it make a difference in output?

Comment: No, just a way to get the output in the Visual Studio output-window. The cout output is swallowed somewhere and doesn't show up.

Comment: Hi Shyamal, could you fix your bug? Then please accept the answer, thanks ^^